# How to reslove "product-pkg-utility failed with exit code -1" error for release build

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I am getting "Command  failed with exit code -1" error when compiling iPhone App for Device - 3.0 | Release build.

I recently installed the iPhone OS 3.0 upgrade on my iMac for developing iPhone Apps in XCode. The App I've been developing started throwing errors when I would try and compile for 3.0 (previously worked in 2.2.1). I fixed all of the errors I could, but I am consistently getting the following error:

```
Command <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> failed with exit code -1
```

Any time I try and compile for the device (even 2.2.1 now...)

It works fine in the simulator (building for both release and debug) but will not work for the device (for release or debug).

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like this might be because I installed the "Snow Leopard" version of the 3.0 SDK instead of the "Leopard" version (I'm just a poor ignorant PC guy who has no idea which animal his OS is named after and just wishes the would call it "X.5" or "X.6" to simplify things).